# Nifi 2.0.0 (Process flows are not progressing in all Processors.)

Tags: apache-nifi

I installed Nifi 2.0.0 with Java 21 with single-user mode, and have been able to recreate my original process groups and process flows manually.
I sometimes can get the processor to process through the flow but, most times it will not progress past the first processor.
Even if I "Run Once" the following process is never executed.  There is also no entry in the queue.
I unexpectedly got one process group to work but still can not get the others to.  Anyone experiencing this issue?

Setting up a new version of Nifi 2.0.0 and was expecting the processors to work as it did in 1.13.2.

Comment: Operating system Windows server 2019 running on a VM with 8gb RAM and two CPUs.